# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting Formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I am doing a formula in conditional formatting and I need it to be relative to each of the 1500 rows but it keeps retrieving an absolute value. how do I get around putting a new formatting formula for each row? 
this is my formula:

```
=AND(G5<I2,ISBLANK(H5)=True)
```

need it to be applied, relatively, to E5:E1500.

Comment: formula not showing on post for some reason. it's: =AND(G5<I2,ISBLANK(H5)=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AND(G5 < I$2, ISBLANK(H5))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=AND(G5 < I$2, ISBLANK(H5), LEN(G5))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: first one worked perfectly thank you!! not sure how Len applies ‍♀️

Comment: LEN is kinda opposite of ISBLANK